# How to find coordinates of $D$

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

How can I find the coordinates $D$ if I have the other coordinates of a parallelogram $A(-3/-2)$, $B(4/1)$, $C(6/5)$, $D(?/?)$.
[image: Parallelogram ABCD]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

by the parallelogram low you have:
$$
\overrightarrow {AC}=\overrightarrow {AB}+\overrightarrow {AD}
$$
so
$$
\overrightarrow {AD}=\overrightarrow {AC}-\overrightarrow {AB}
$$

can you do from this?

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me.

Comment: But this solution is definitely not unique: given three non colinear points there are some possibilities to complete them to a parallelogram.

Comment: If the order$ABCD$ is fixed as in the figure the solution is unique.